# Display JSON data on dynamically generated textbox (via HTML helpers)

Tags: html, json, model-view-controller, textbox, html-helper

I want to assign the value of "version" retrieved via AJAX call in JSON format to the textbox, but item.version is giving me error. Could anyone please help me with the same.

```
$.each(data, function (i, item) { 

var row = $("<tr />")
$("#SomeTable").append(row);
row.append($("<td>" + '@Html.TextBox("SomeName", item.version , new { @class = "form-control" })' +"</td>"));

});
```

EDIT - Included the piece of code from where "item" comes from.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting?

Comment: Can you please include in your question what the item is / where it comes from? Obviously you will get an error trying to access that if you don't have that object available/defined as it appears from the currently included code.

Comment: $.each(data, function (i, item) {


                        var row = $("<tr />")
                        $("#SomeTable").append(row);
                       
                        row.append($("<td>" + '@Html.TextBox("SomeName", item.version , new { @class = "form-control" })' +"</td>"));